# Easy way to auto-move images in css

Tags: php, html, css

My goal is to take an image (size varies) and have it fit within a set container (330x330 pixels).  I do not want to resize the image.  I want to simply have the css have it automatically move itself to cetner the picture as if it were cropped with 330x330.

If I put in a picture that is smaller than 330x330 though then i supposed it would have to scale it up.  For instance if it were 200x800 then it would stretch it out and then shift the image vertically to show the center?

Is this possible or is what I am trying to do impossible without a lot of annoying PHP?  Thanks

Comment: take a look here http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/03/masking-images-with-css-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
​div {
  width: 330px;
  height: 330px;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/800/200") 50% 50% no-repeat;   
  background-size: cover;
}​
```

It should works on: IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.